# Emacs ammonite-mode

Tags: scala, emacs, ammonite

Is there a half-decent Emacs mode for [Ammonite scripts](https://ammonite.io/#ScriptFiles) somewhere? When I try to use `scala-mode` it doesn't work that well. Errors on most every line.